# How do I pass multiple values in one dropdown menu?

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to pass a value of the artistName as well as the artistId simultaneously to allow both fields to be written to the table. I need both values to allow for a hyperlink on the artistName to query the single artist. The artistId field is a primary key for the artists table, and a foreign key on the albums table.

Is there a way of making a dual-value name that allows me to easily separate the 2 values from each other and write the name and id to the table simultaneously, or perhaps a way of parsing the 2 fields after the request.getParameter into something more usable?

Here's what I have for this field...

JSP

```
<tr><td><b>Artist*</b></td>

<td><select name="artistName">
<c:forEach items="${Artists}" var="Artist">
<!--    <option> <c:out value="${Artist.artistName}?artistId=${Artist.artistId}&   artistName=${Artist.artistName}"/></option>${Artist.artistId} -->
<option> <c:out value="${Artist.artistName} ${Artist.artistId}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select></td></tr>
```

Comment: I don't understand... why the hell would you need to send the name if you're already sending the id, which will let you retrieve the name with a simple join later on ?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to this, and trying to learn. Forgive me if I don't know a better way, that's the point of asking. It would be a lot more helpful to expand on your thought, there.

Comment: Well, typically, if someone select an artist in the dropdown (by the name), the value to send and to store will be this artist's id. That's basically all you need to store in the table you'll be recording to, as you already have another table where you know the artist details and of course the id.
So you should set the value of your option to be only the artist id, and the text to be the artist's name, as the id probably is of no interest for your users...

Comment: Comparing this forEach dropdown menu to the others I have used before, where the value being passed is labelled as such on the left, followed by the display value on the right that shows on the page, like this...

<option value="Studio Album">Studio Album</option>

Now, if I follow that pattern, what I should have to display the artistName, but pass the artistId is this...

<option> <c:out value="${Artist.artistId}"/>${Artist.artistName}</option>

...but what I have is a display of both the ID and name. Is there any way to make the ID hidden?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send both the **NAME** and the **ID** of the artist,
What you could do, is when entering them in your foreach loop, basically you would seperate them with a ':'

So that when you submit the actual form, the value of the select would be artistName:artistID

from there you could split the string on the ':' to insert them both as seperate parts into your table.

Comment: I tried that, and perhaps I don't know how you mean to do that. It didn't work.

Comment: May I know what technique you are using to pass this to the database? Since this is HTML being generated it could be done via an AJAX request etc..

Comment: After request.getParameter for each field, I am using Hibernate to save...

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
   Albums albums = new Albums();
   albums.setArtist(artist);
   albums.setAlbumTitle(albumTitle);
   albums.setYearReleased(yearReleased);
   
   default for null date field here...
    
    albums.setYearReleased(yearReleased2);
   }
   albums.setGenre(genre);
   albums.setLabel(label);
   albums.setAlbumType(albumType);
   albums.setProducer(producer);
   session.save(albums);
   tx.commit();
   session.close();

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I think this would do the trick :

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Artist*</b></td>
    <td>
        <select name="artistName">
        <c:forEach items="${Artists}" var="Artist">
            <option <c:out value="${Artist.artistId}"/>>${Artist.artistName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Please note I'm not into Java/JSP myself so I'm not sure about the syntax, but the id is to input the `value` attribute INSIDE the option tag. I think that's your problem but it's hard to be sure without a copy of the source of your HTML output.
Please note also that the title of your question is misleading on your goal. As I said in my comments, you actually don't need (at least not from where I see it) to pass multiple values, only the artist id is actually needed.